# How to connect to mongodb from Firefox plugin

Tags: javascript, mongodb, spidermonkey

HI all,

I write a Firefox plugin and want to save data to mongodb (this plugin use for internal application), I use spidermonkey, what I known is mongodb have mongo is a javascript spidermon shell, but I dont know how to connect to mongodb from my plugin.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if this would be possible. Just because the server has Spidermonkey embedded does mean anything for the Spidermonkey your firefox runs. You could use some REST solution http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface